# Facebook login issue in iOS with latest SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm implementing app with face book login. i need to access user "public profile" and as well as "email id" also. Here email id is must. i am able to login but after enter login details it shows review page, in that review page it shows "Edit info you provide" button, here i am facing issue. i have 2 doubts here 1) is it possible to disable "edit info you provide" option (or) 2) is it possible to disable user interaction for email field like public profile. my code is below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

    self.loginButton.delegate = self;
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile",@"email"];
}
#pragma mark - Private method implementation

-(void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide{
    self.lblUsername.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.lblEmail.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.profilePicture.hidden = shouldHide;
}


#pragma mark - FBLoginView Delegate method implementation

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"You are logged in.";

    [self toggleHiddenState:NO];
}


-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
    NSLog(@"%@", user);
    self.profilePicture.profileID = user.id;
    self.lblUsername.text = user.name;
    self.lblEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
}


-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"You are logged out";

    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
}


-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I read from the documentation in developers.facebook.com for the first and second doubt the answer is No. The user can revoke permission even after he gave permission initially, it is a security feature added from facebook. What you can do is check what permission is granted to you with:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/permissions" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
__block NSString *alertText;
__block NSString *alertTitle;
if (!error){
    // Walk the list of permissions looking to see if email has been granted
    NSArray *permissions = (NSArray *)[result data];
    BOOL emailPermission = FALSE;
    for (NSDictionary *perm in permissions) {
        if ([[perm objectForKey:@"permission"] isEqualToString:@"email"] &&
            [[perm objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"granted"]) {
            emailPermission = TRUE;
            NSLog(@"email granted.");
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: can you explain it. how we can get result here. i am doing this way.

Comment: [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:
         ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
             // Retrieve the app delegate
             AppDelegate *appDelegate  = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
 [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
         }];

Comment: Just add the 'FBRequestConnection' block inside your 'openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions' and then inside 'FBRequestConnection' block check  'if (emailPermission) {//then access is granted } else { //Show an alertview and tell the user that he should give permission to his email address}'

Comment: is it possible to restrict user like, to come out from the review view until select email permission

Comment: lets say until select email should stay in review screen. even if click on OK also should give same alert message, is it possible?

Comment: Can you be more clear on the review view, I don't understand ? if you mean the facebook review view, then you do not have any control on that, you can not do that.

Comment: yes after enter face book details we will see review screen with OK and Cancel Buttons right. is it possible to handle those buttons actions

Comment: Then no you can not do that because you don't have any control on the facebook app.

Comment: actually i am able to check wether user gave permission for email or not with your code. but i am not able to give a option to select email again if user already deselect email . any idea

Comment: i want to give a chance to select the email  , if user deselect already first time. because email is necessary to login to my app. thats way i want to restict the user until provide email permission

Comment: Yes I understand you, but it is not much you can do, I had the same issue the facebook with login, but you can only check in your app, if the user granted access, and on the alertview add two button, one that says give permission, if he clicks it redirect him again to facebook.

Comment: i did same thing already but it not shows review screen to give permission again. Once if you click on OK , it wont show review screen again to the same user to grant the required permissions